# validation message is not appearing properly

Tags: laravel

In the validation.php file the error message is like this:

```
'after_or_equal'       => 'A :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.',
```

However when this error occurs the message that appears is :

```
validation.after_or_equal
```

Do you know why?

Code to show the messages in the view:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Store method with validation:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'startDate' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i',
        'endDate' => 'required|date_format:d F Y - H:i|after_or_equal:startDate',

    ]);
}
```

View that includes the errors file:

```
@extends('layouts')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid px-4">

@include('includes.errors')

<form id="edit_admins" method="post" class="clearfix"
  action="{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{csrf_field()}}

....

</form>

@endsection
```

Comment: Please add the validation code that's in the controller

Comment: Thanks. I update the question with that.

Comment: Would you be able to post the code of the view where the errors are posted? I was able to test this code and have it display the errors properly.

Comment: Thanks, I update the question with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So confirm where did you put your code `'after_or_equal' => 'A :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.',`, because if you put in wring place you will receive this message `validation.after_or_equal`.
You need to put in this place on **validation.php**:

```
<?php

return [

   /*
   |------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Validation Language Lines
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
   | the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
   | as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
   |
   */

     'accepted'             => 'The :attribute must be accepted.',
     'active_url'           => 'The :attribute is not a valid URL.',
     'after'                => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
     'after_or_equal'       => 'A :attribute must be a date after or equal to :date.',
     ...
```

If the things okay, check your app locale, maybe you're in another language.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is because the app locale, so if we change the app locale do you know how can we do to have the proper validation message?

Comment: Nice, so you can use this package https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang, there you can find almost every language.
To change your language validation, manually create a **folder** with the language that you want in `application\resources\lang\{language}\`, and inside create the **validation.php** file and put the validation text.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the `date_format` validation rule should have the date format surrounded by `"`.

Here is the updated snippet.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [

        'startDate' => 'required|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"',
        'endDate' => 'required|date_format:"d F Y - H:i"|after_or_equal:startDate',

    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the message appears the same "validation.after_or_equal
".

Comment: Darn. Does this happen if you fail validation on `startDate`?

Comment: Yes, the message is the same but "validation.date_format".